# Using es6 spread without Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm not a big fan of Object.assign, in my opinion, it is hard to read and not elegant, I try to avoid it. Somewhere I saw this in redux reducer

```
case ADD_TODO:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: [
      ...state.todos,
      {
        text: action.text
      }
    ]
  })
```

Just curious is Object assign looks good above? Why not just do this instead?

```
case ADD_TODO:
  return {
    ...state,
    todos: [
      ...state.todos,
      {
        text: action.text
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You can. Code you read online isn't always written in the style you'd like to see

Comment: make a cleaner-looking helper: `function update(obj){return Object.assign({}, state, obj);}` which enables you to reduce repeated code down to basically just the new literal w/backwards compat.

Comment: @dandavis—but that gives a different result. The OP is looking for a deep(ish?) copy.

Comment: it does the same thing as the outside of the first example, it's not a complete thing...

Answer (score 1):

> Why not just do this instead?

Because it's not valid ES6 anymore.

The [object rest/spread syntax *proposal*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) had been around for some time but only was accepted for ES2018. See [here](http://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html) for details.

Comment: Isn't ECMAScript 2018 now called [*ECMAScript 2019*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) (where the current version is [*ECMAScript 2017*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html) aka ed 8)?

Comment: @RobG The version they will release this year is called ES2018 (or ES9). The TC39 repo you linked seems to be updated for next year's release already.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting a 2018 version but it seems to have gone into limbo. Where do I find drafts when they're in transition between the [TC39 repository](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262) and [ecma-international site](http://ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)?

Comment: From a technical perspective, yes it's not. But everybody and their mother uses a transpiler when working with React.js. You'd have to comment on that nested spread as well then `state.todos`

Comment: @Andrew I don't get the comment part, what do you mean?